Is there any theoretical way to control the production from proton/antiproton annihilation?
I've studied proton/antiproton annihilation on and off for a while now and thought on it while driving, and I've never been able to find any exact confirmation on whether it's production can be theoretically controlled or if it's truly inobservably random.
I have a theory of "environmental doping" for P/ApA, mostly used as a hypothetical to first establish whether it's possible at all, that hypothetically were I to annihilate a proton and antiproton under an extreme electric charge, would it lead to a statistically lower or even absent production of electrons in it's annihilation? I'm aware the production is randomized via the, perhaps inobservable states of the sea-quarks but due to conservation I find it hard to believe an extremely energetic electric field wouldn't block or at least reduce it's conversion in the form of electrons, and raise it's production of other particles such as gamma rays.
I've done my own research but I've hit the limit where all I know to do further is read entire textbooks on quantum physics and, obviously the time-saving to simply ask a specialized expert my singular question is what this forum is for.
